# Moving Div inside the loop in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to move the `bullets` inside the Loop specifically under the Name.
I tried this one but not working.

```js
(function($) {
  var bullets = $(".elementor-main-swiper.swiper-container").find($('.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-clickable.swiper-pagination-bullets'));

  $('.elementor-testimonial').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this),
      target = _this.find('.elementor-testimonial__cite');
    bullets.insertAfter(target);
    alert(hello);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Please see here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16X1-DgCA7gIi50zl7qlE0gL4E9hDeR5P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Without seeing your html it's hard to provide you a good answer, but you can try `target.append(bullets)`

Comment: Hi edit the post and add the html structure, but will what you suggested too!

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML Structure directly to your post and don't link to any google drive link that might be unavailable in the future.

Comment: Hi I can't paste my html code, it says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: You really should add more details; for starters, what specifically does “not working” look like? What is it doing that it shouldn’t, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t actually said what’s wrong with the code you’ve written, so I can only assume that your bullet points get added only to the *last* testimonial, not to all of them.

This is because when you append element A to element B, if element A already exists in the DOM, it will be *moved* rather than copied.

If you want to add the bullet points to each testimonial you’ll need to copy the bullet points using jQuery’s `clone()` method:

```js
bullets.clone().insertAfter(target);
```